# combine values with select_related

Tags: django

I have to models "Product" and "user" and post model has user foreignKey I want to query posts join with user with only ("username","name) fields

I tried to use

```
Product.objects.values('id', 'title',"user__username","user__name")
```

and i got

```
{
   id,
   title,
   username,
   name
}
```

but i want something like this

```
{
   id,
   title,
   user:{
    username,
    name
   }
}
```

Comment: do you use django serializers? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: yes but i dont select field like password at the first place

Comment: Can you share the serializer(s) and model(s) you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
Product.objects.annotate(user_info=JSONObject(username="user__username", name="user__name")).values("id", "title", "user_info")
```

New key (user_info) should not be in conflict with your model keys

If you use drf:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user=UserSerializer()
  class Meta:
      fields = [
         "id",
         "title",
         "user",
      ]
```